# Best way for a one armed character to wield guns?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, house-rules, gunslinger

My homebrew gunslinger7/sorcerer7 just got his arm cut off during some shenanigans last session. It was awesome. But he almost exclusively uses a revolver, which doesn't say it requires two hands to load but its seems like only having one hand would make it a bit harder. My question is how I can use spells and/or abilities to help him operate firearms? I.e. animate object, mage hand, telekinesis, etc. The gunslinger class is a class I got off the D&D wiki page and reworked myself. Not looking for any super mechanical answers just idea generation.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! You should [edit] in the approprite system tag for whatever RPG your are playing/asking about (eg. [dnd-5e] for D&D 5e), you are unsure, feel free to ask us here in the comments, we'll help you out as best we can. Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Are you using [Matt Mercer's gunslinger](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/170778/Gunslinger-Martial-Archetype-for-Fighters) (which also appears on [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#Gunslinger) due to an advertising partnership between Critical Role and DDB)? Also, are you looking to counteract specific mechanical disadvantages specified by the rules (and if so, what are they), or are you simply looking for idea generation to explain the flavor? (The latter, idea-generation, is primarily opinion-based and not a good fit for the StackExchange format.)

Comment: Given your recent edit to clarify that you are indeed looking for idea-generation, such questions are unfortunately not a good fit for our site. You might be better off asking on a forum; [we have some recommendations here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).